# kivyMD list update Icon

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

I am using the following function to create an MDlist TwoLineIconListItem in a scrollview. What I would like to do is change the icon in another function. I thought something like `x.icon = 'New_icon'` might work but didn't. Not sure where to look to get the desired result.

```
def rule_list(self):
        '''Query of all rules and generates a list view under the rule tab....not really working all the way yet'''
        db.execute('''SELECT * from rules''')
        self.rows = db.fetchall()
        for r in self.rows:
            self.rule = f'{self.cfg["host"]}:{self.cfg["port"]}/api/firewall/filter/getRule/{r[2]}'
            rules = TwoLineIconListItem(
                text=r[1],
                secondary_text=r[2],
                on_release=lambda x: threading.Thread(
                    target=self.rule_on_click, args=(x.secondary_text, x), daemon=True).start()
            )
            self.check = requests.get(url=self.rule, auth=(
                self.key, self.secret), verify=False)
            if self.check.status_code == 200:
                check_rule = json.loads(self.check.text)
                if check_rule['rule']['enabled'] == '1':
                    rules.add_widget(IconLeftWidget(
                        icon='checkbox-marked-circle-outline'
                    ))
                else:
                    rules.add_widget(IconLeftWidget(
                        icon='checkbox-blank-circle-outline'
                    ))

            self.root.ids.ruleList.add_widget(rules)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using the following in the function that had the logic for assigning the correct icon.

```
x.children[0].children[0].icon = new_icon
```